# iOS set background color for all viewcontroller self.view's

Tags: ios, view, uiviewcontroller

Is there a way to set same background image for all views?

Setting same background in all `viewDidLoad:` methods. It's not cool.

Comment: It's only one line of code, just copy and paste. How many views do you have?

Comment: Loop through all subviews and apply the background is the only way I can think of.

Comment: are you sure you don't want to set their background color to transparent and set the color once for the container view?

Comment: Now you have some options. If you are not satisfied, make an abstract subclass with red background, and let all the vcs inherit from that object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using [`UIAppearance`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) in iOS5+:

```
[[UIView appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

*NOTE: `UIView` conforms to `<UIAppearance, UIAppearanceContainer>` protocols but does not mark  any properties as `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR` for some reason.*

Comment: true, but this will set the background for all subviews that subclass UIView (almost everything) including Buttons, Labels etc. ...

Answer (score 11):

You can create a custom class, let's call it a TemplateView, which is subclass of UIView.
Then using xib/storyboards select the controller view and identity inspector change the Class property to 'TemplateView'.

Subsequently using an UIAppearance change the background color of the template view to the desired one.

```
 [[TemplateView appearance]setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

That will change the background color of each of the template views in your project.
I think it's better solution than

```
[[UIView appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

because we don't change the background of everything, just our custom class.
Hope it will help.

Comment: This is a much better answer than the accepted answer. Giving all the UIViews a background will produce many unexpected side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a good idea, but if you really want to do this, you could do something like this:

```
- (void)setBGColor:(UIColor *)color forAllSubviewsOf:(UIView *)view
{
    [view setBackgroundColor:color];
    for (UIView *sub in view.subviews)
        [self setBGColor:color forAllSubviewsOf:sub];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use Method Swizzling kind some feature to change all views colour or image setting.

Check following

https://wiredcraft.com/blog/method-swizzling-ios/